# A generic way to convert between types in Haskell

Tags: haskell, type-conversion

To start off, this question is not like the many other SO questions with similar topics, e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40316051/1382487), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1894365/1382487), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9511832/convert-one-data-type-to-another), or even [here](https://wiki.haskell.org/Converting_numbers). There are many others - I am not listing all of them as they are mostly about automatic conversion. My question is different. I am writing my own conversion and am looking for a generic way to implement that.

I have a type class `Graph` from which I derive different graph representations: `GraphSet` (set representation), `AdjMatrix`, `AdjList`.

```
class Graph a where
  newGraph      :: a
  hasVertex     :: a -> Int -> Bool
  hasEdge       :: a -> (Int,Int) -> Bool
  addEdge       :: a -> (Int,Int) -> a
  addVertex     :: a -> a
  removeEdge    :: a -> (Int,Int) -> a
  removeVertex  :: a -> Int -> a
  inDegree      :: a -> Int -> Int
  outDegree     :: a -> Int -> Int
```

I want some way to formally capture that any representation is convertible to any other. Correspondingly, I want to write 2 `convert` functions for each of the above 3 representations. I am unable to find a way to do this in a generic manner.

My initial attempt was to write a [multi-parameter type class](https://wiki.haskell.org/Multi-parameter_type_class)

```
class Equivalent a b where
  convert :: b -> a
```

but that gets problematic as there are 2 `a`s for every `b`, e.g.

```
instance Equivalent GraphSet AdjMatrix where
  convert g@(AdjMatrix mat) = newGraph :: GraphSet -- stub
instance Equivalent AdjList AdjMatrix where
  convert g@(AdjMatrix mat) = newGraph :: AdjList -- stub, error
```

I could of course write differently named functions but there must be a generic way to do this.

Before anyone points out, I am aware of the option of using `show` and then reading the resulting String into the other type. That does not solve the above problem.

---

UPDATE: As pointed out in the comments, the code above works just fine. Due to some reasons (experience with other languages, other errors) I was wrongly under the impression that Haskell will not differentiate between functions based on return type only. As Li-yao mentions below, `read` does exactly that.

Comment: "but that gets problematic" What exactly is problematic? Can you show code that should be valid but isn't because of these definitions?

Comment: The problem is illustrated in the code just below the quoted line (the code contained a typo earlier which may have led to your confusion and which I just corrected). There will need to be 2 functions called `convert` both of which take an `AdjMatrix` as argument but each has a different return type. As fas as I know, Haskell does not differentiate between functions based on return type only.This gets compounded when trying to `convert` other representations.

Comment: "Haskell does not differentiate between functions based on return type only".

What do you mean by that? Haskell can overload a function only on its return type, that's how `read` works for example. What error are you getting?

Comment: [I don't see any error](http://ideone.com/mAaJHW). Can you show a [mcve]?

Comment: Indeed. I tried the code given in the OP just now and there is no error. The OP seems silly now. I shall remove it - is that against SO protocol?

Comment: @wsaleem it's considered impolite to delete a question when somebody may already have spent effort answering it, but in this case I don't see any problem. Still better would be if you _added an own answer_ showing a complete example of how this does in fact work.

Comment: @n.m. If you paste your code from ideone as an answer, I will accept it. That will put an end to this.

Comment: You could use `fromGraph :: forall q. Graph q => q -> a` in your first typeclass to provide the stronger garuntee that you can convert like this for *any* Graph, which is what your question says, but not what you want.

Comment: You could define some interchange format (I.e. Some representation of a graph which is easy to quickly generate from most types and to produce from most types) and add functions to convert from/to it. E.g. You might have `fromVE :: ([Int],[(Int,Int)]) -> a` and a similar function to reverse it. Then you can write `convertGraph = fromVE . toVE`